# nginx 502 error in POST request when uploading file in API request

Tags: php, laravel, http, nginx, fastcgi

#### Environment:

- Laravel Version: 5.8.29
- PHP Version `$ php --version`: PHP 7.2.24 (cli)
- NGINX Version `$ nginx -v`: nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

---

#### Problem Statement:

I'm getting 502 bad gateway error on one particular endpoint from NGINX when trying to `POST` request, while including file in API request.

However, It's working properly on other endpoint, where I don't need to add file in request.

What could be possibly wrong here?

---

#### Error

> NGINX 502 Bad Gateway

##### Logs

```
$ sudo tail -30 /var/log/nginx/error.log
[error] 4713#4713: *705118 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 111.11.11.111, server: domain.com, request: "POST /action/api/path HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com", referrer: "domain.com/path"

$ sudo tail /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log
WARNING: [pool www] child 28524 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 
NOTICE: [pool www] child 8033 started
```

---

#### Files & Configuration:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {


    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    # max post size
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com`

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /path/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https :// domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` **(Pool directives)**

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf` **(Global directives)**

```
[global]

pid = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.pid

error_log = /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log

include=/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

---

**PHP cURL request**

```
private $headers = [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
];

private $baseURL = 'http://otherdomain.in/api/v1/';


private function postRequest($data, $endpoint) {

    if ( !is_null($this->apiToken) ) {

        $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer {$this->apiToken}";
        array_push($this->headers, $authorization);
    }

    $url = "{$this->baseURL}/{$endpoint}";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $responseJSON = curl_exec($ch);

    $response = json_decode($responseJSON, TRUE);

    return $response
}
```

---

#### EDIT 1:

I've restarted `fastcgi` process using following [query](https://serverfault.com/a/486591)

```
$ sudo service php7.2-fpm restart

$ sudo tail /var/log/php7.2-fpm.log
NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
WARNING: [pool www] child 28870 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 53.229996 seconds from start
NOTICE: [pool www] child 28879 started
NOTICE: Terminating ...
NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 29564
NOTICE: ready to handle connections
NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
WARNING: [pool www] child 29592 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 17.115362 seconds from start
NOTICE: [pool www] child 29596 started
```

---

#### EDIT 2:

I've found that my `opcache` is already comment. So there is no point of disabling or increasing its memory limit as per following [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/830030)

`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini`

```
[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
;opcache.enable=0

; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled for the CLI version of PHP
;opcache.enable_cli=0

; The OPcache shared memory storage size.
;opcache.memory_consumption=196
```

---

#### EDIT 3:

When I changed `listen` as per following [query](https://serverfault.com/a/923314/621140)

`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

```
listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

to

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

```
$ sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
Job for php7.2-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php7.2-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


$ systemctl status php7.2-fpm.service
● php7.2-fpm.service - The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.2-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-11-13 06:13:51 UTC; 1min 21s ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.2(8)
  Process: 30120 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.2 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 30120 (code=exited, status=78)

systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager...
php-fpm7.2[30120]: [13-Nov-2021 06:13:51] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1
php-fpm7.2[30120]: [13-Nov-2021 06:13:51] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
systemd[1]: php7.2-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
systemd[1]: php7.2-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.2 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

---

#### EDIT 4:

As pointed by @valery-viktorovsky in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69953996/14138027). I've changed the version of PHP from 7.4 to 7.2, as I only have php 7.2.

> It looks like you use 2 versions of PHP, 7.2 and 7.4

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
  ..
}
```

Still getting same logs

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

[error] 23250#23250: *74 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 111.11.11.111, server: domain.com, request: "POST /action/api/path  HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com", referrer: "domain.com/path"
```

---

#### EDIT 5:

I tried adding the following as per these answer [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23751477) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39922126) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23805207)

```
http {

        fastcgi_read_timeout 400s;

        # max post size
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        send_timeout                10m;
        client_header_timeout       10m;
        client_body_timeout         10m;

        large_client_header_buffers 8 1024k;

        server {

                location / {
                        proxy_buffer_size 1024k;
                        proxy_buffers 4 1024k;
                        proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
                }
        }
}
```

---

Comment: Show cUrl request exported from Chrome too

Comment: @Justinas, My backend server is making api call. While frontend is just use for post data to backend server via ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use 2 versions of PHP, 7.2 and 7.4

> Environment:
> PHP Version $ php --version: PHP 7.2.24 (cli)

but in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com` config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  ..
}
```

You can get rid of 7.2 and use 7.4 only and then check the php logs again.